# R Shiny Store Data Locally Lags from 3rd Input

Tags: r, shiny

I have an R Shiny code that is supposed to store data locally and display it immediately after the input. I use the code below and for some unknown reason from the 3rd input the data is lagging by one row. For example, if I submit d1 for a name it shows immediately, then d2 which shows up immediately as well, but when I submit the 3rd value then it does not show up immediately and only shows up after I submit the 4th value. From now the table is lagging by one.
Do you have any clue why this is happening?

```
library(shiny)

# Define the fields we want to save from the form
fields <- c("name")

# Save a response
saveData <- function(dt) {
    if (exists("res")) {
        res <<- append(res, dt)
    } else {
        res <<- dt
    }
}

# Load all previous res
loadData <- function() {
    if (exists("res")) {
        res
    }
}

# Shiny app with that the user can submit data for
shinyApp(
    ui = fluidPage(
        textOutput("res"), tags$hr(),
        textInput("name", "Name", ""),
        actionButton("submit", "Submit")
    ),
    server = function(input, output, session) {

        # When the Submit button is clicked, save the form data
        observeEvent(input$submit, {
            saveData(input$name)
        })

        # Show the previous res
        # (update with current response when Submit is clicked)
        output$res <- renderText({
            input$submit
            loadData()
        })     
    }
)
```

Comment: Could you please provide more information on what happens on the loadData and saveData methods? In addition, do you have to use an actionButton? are reactive updates not working well in your case?

Comment: Hi @Omri374, the code is fully reproducible, you can paste and run. The weird behavior starts after 3rd submission.

Comment: I ran it multiple times and each time I got a concatenated string, even after the 3rd time